# how to compile ts file to minified js file

Tags: typescript

I have created typescript project and when I compile project then all ts files gets compiled and creates js and map files.
I want to create javascript minified files instead of js files.
how it can be done.please help me.

Comment: use a minifier on the code after it's been compiled

Comment: I don't want to use grunt file.

Comment: then you can't. tsc doesn't offer you the option to minify the outputed js.

Comment: what closure compiler do?

Comment: do closure compiler minify js file at the time of compilation?

Comment: Why don't use uglify or other minifying tool after using tsc? You may use gulp task or other build system to do this continuously on every ts-file change

Comment: Actually i was thinking it can be done without using grunt or gulp file, but it may not possible.thank you.

Comment: it's not mandatory to use grunt or gulp, but you will need an external minifier since the typescript compiler doesn't provide one. :)